# Why does a query fail with "AnalysisException: Expected only partition pruning predicates"?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

While executing below query on Spark shell, I am facing partition error:

> Expected only partition pruning predicates: ((((isnotnull(tenant_suite#478) && isnotnull(DS#477)) && (DS#477 >= 2017-06-01)) && (DS#477 <= 2017-06-25)) && (tenant_suite#478 = SAMS_CORESITE))

Not sure what error spark is throwing . Can anyone please help me with this?

```
SELECT 
  A.*
FROM
        (-----------SUBQUERY 1
        SELECT * 
        FROM 
            T2 --  PARTITION COLUMNS ARE DS AND TENANT_SUITE
        WHERE   
            DS BETWEEN '2017-06-01'AND '2017-06-25'--date_sub(TO_DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP())),1)
            AND tenant_suite = 'CORESITE'
        ) a

        JOIN

        ( -----------SUBQUERY 1
        SELECT
             concat(concat(visid_high,'-',visid_low),'-',visit_num) AS VISIT_ID
            ,concat(visid_high,'-',visid_low) AS VISITOR_ID
            ,MAX(DS) AS EVENT_DT
        FROM
            T2  -- PARTITION COLUMNS ARE DS AND TENANT_SUITE
        WHERE
            tenant_suite = 'CORESITE'
            AND DS BETWEEN '2017-06-01'AND '2017-06-25' --date_sub(TO_DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP())),1) 
        GROUP BY concat(concat(visid_high,'-',visid_low),'-',visit_num),concat(visid_high,'-',visid_low)
        ) B
            ON A.VISIT_ID = B.VISIT_ID
            AND A.VISITOR_ID = B.VISITOR_ID
            AND A.VISIT_DT = B.EVENT_DT
    group by a.VISIT_DT;
```

Comment: Can you show the entire `AnalysisException` with the `nonPartitionPruningPredicates` that should be displayed after the `Expected only partition pruning predicates` error message? Can you also "destructure" the query and execute SELECTs one by one until you find the root cause? Can you check partitionColumnNames for tables `T1` and `T2`?

Comment: The total Partition Message is :"Expected only partition pruning predicates: ((((isnotnull(tenant_suite#474) && isnotnull(DS#473)) && (DS#473 >= 2017-06-26)) && (DS#473 <= 2017-07-09)) && (tenant_suite#474 = CORE))  .........   When I executed the subqueries individually, I faced exactly same error . For T1 there is no partition key defined as I haven't done while creating the table and for T2 it is DS and Tenant_suite.

Comment: Can you edit your original question to add the entire `AnalysisException` and the subqueries individually one by one. Can you also add the info about partition keys for each table? Edit your question as comments are not very suitable for this. Thanks.

Comment: Jacek. I am able execute this query when the partition columns being used in WHERE clause are in LOWERCASE. Is Spark case sensitive for partition column?

Comment: @Umamaheshwar Yes. In spark, partition columns are case sensitive. This is because the partition columns in spark are structured by creating directories with same name on HDFS file systems, which is a case sensitive file system.

Answer (score 9):

In Spark Partition Columns are case sensitive- 
[Spark Jira Issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-19811)

Comment: When I came across this, I said to myself, "there's no way this is the answer." A day later, I'm back to give you a +1. It's the first time I've come across a SQL-like language that's case sensitive, some of the time.

Comment: @BenOgorek +1 I was in the same position as you.

Comment: Hit this problem and find this helpful answer！